# Failed to import pyOpt module

Tags: python, optimization, installation, jupyter-notebook

I have installed the pyOpt package through the setup.py and in the beginning, I was not able to install it in python 3.7 but able to install it in python 2.7 with all dependencies which is required to work with pyopt but still, I am facing some issues.
That is i am not able to use all the optimizer that is available there. Only able to use ALHSO and ALPSO in jupyter notebook but want to use NLPQL and NSGA-II.

```
from pyOpt.pyALHSO.pyALHSO import ALHSO
from pyOpt.pyNLPQL.pyNLPQL import NLPQL
```

1st one is not giving any error but second one is raising 'NLPQL shared library failed to import'
NOt able to figure why 2 modules (ALHSO, ALPSO) is working but rest not working.
Also I am using 32-bit system. Any help is appreciated thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you obtained the NLPQLP source code needed for it to compile?

You could test to see if the code is generally working by running an example, i.e.

```
python examples\autorefine.py
```

Comment: No, I didn't get the source code for NLPQLP.

Comment: Then check out the gradient-based algorithm SLSQP.  In my experience it is not as fast (i.e. number of iterations needed) as NLPQLP, but is a good alternative.